# unable to set cursor on right side

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

the cursor not set on right side it will show on left side.what should i do please help i want cursor will blink from right side.it will always start from left during execution.

```
    private void button8_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(button8.Text);
        if (editText1.IsFocused)
        {
            editText1.Text += a.ToString();
        }
        else
            editText2.Text += a.ToString();
    }
```

[the cursor is not set on right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMrX9.png)

Comment: Are you wanting to use Right To Left text as is used in Arabic and Hebrew? Or do you want the cursor to jump to the end on this one entry?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear, and you should formulate it better next time. Also what has your button click has to do with any of it?

If you only want to set the cursor on the right side you can use SetSelection:

```
EditText edittext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edittext);
edittext.Text = "test";
edittext.SetSelection(edittext.Text.Length);
```

If you would like Right-to-Left text:

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```